# Is it possible to check in an additional piece of luggage in Singapore on a layover?

Tags: transit, luggage, layovers, singapore

Say you are travelling from Australia to Dubai with a layover in Singapore. If I have a transit visa for Singapore, I can go out and very well buy some stuff. The question is, can I check in these items at Singapore?

Comment: Are you planning to enter Singapore and buy outside the duty free area?  Or are you thinking about shopping in Changi's duty free area?

Comment: @Tom: Outside the airport. Although I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Actually it does effect things, as purchasing outside the airport means you would check your extra "bag" at the check in counter before re-entering the airport secure area.  Buying inside the duty free area means attempting to gate check your bag.  Both cases have different rules.  The former being subjected to your ticket's baggage rules / fees, the later at the discretion of the gate agent.

Comment: I am not sure if Changi allows checking in items at the departure gate.

Comment: All airports allow gate checked bags, as that is how wheelchairs, baby strollers and excess carry on bags are accommodated.  But because you would be doing it voluntarily, it would be up to airline policy and at the gate agent's discretion

Answer (score 1):

In principle this is not a problem at all, indeed it's quite common place, assuming you don't exceed any kind of baggage allowance you have on the ticket.